# Where to find street names for each city in US?

Tags: openstreetmap, streets, data

I'm sorry if my question is stupid but I had to ask.

I'm building a database of US states, cities, streets AND their basic relations to each other. I already have state and city tables.

Where can I find street data to purchase?

I know nothing about GIS and I'm too busy to learn it. So I have to buy it i believe.

Comment: You are better off asking this Question on the Open Data Stack Exchange Site [Here!](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You could have asked a larger GPS company like NavTeq or so to get a hold of map data.  Why you're here... I have no idea.

Comment: Didn't know this SE existed! Great Resource.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to extract some information or use [Open Street Maps](http://www.openstreetmap.org) as a Base.

Here you can search for some datasets through [data.gov](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=street&sort=none&ext_location=&ext_bbox=&ext_prev_extent=-139.21874999999997%2C8.754794702435618%2C-61.87499999999999%2C61.77312286453146)

[ArcGis](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=3b93337983e9436f8db950e38a8629af) provides street and highways at a certain resolution.

A quick [google search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=open%20data%20united%20states%20streets%20highways&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ebK-U9j6BMu99AbjnoC4CA#channel=sb&q=spatial%20data%20united%20states%20streets%20highways&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial) may yield you more results depending on what exactly you're looking for. But the above should serve you well!

There may be other resources for actual purchase, be sure to read the fine print on each of these websites depending on the purposes of your project.